# Why is my Herokuapp Secure on Chrome but Not Secure on Microsoft Edge?

Tags: google-chrome, security, heroku, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

It is an app developed with the MERN-stack, deployed to Heroku.

On GitHub I had a number of automated pull requests from `Dependabot` with security vulnerabilities.

Once I fixed them all, my app (On Edge browser) actually said it was Secure, a few days ago.

But now for some reason it's back to (Not Secure) and maybe it doesn't matter, but I'd like my app that's gonna be used by others to be secure as possible.

Comment: Is there any message or error showing when it's not secure? Does the not secure issue only occur on Edge and which version of Edge are you using? Will the issue occur if you don't deploy the app to Heroku? I think you need to provide more details about the issue or the situation which can reproduce the issue. The description above is too vague to locate the issue

Comment: You're right.  It's just that it's not really providing me with info.  I'm referring to the small icon to the left of the URL.  I'll post what it says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution at

https://www.support.com/how-to/how-to-fix-this-site-is-not-secure-error-in-edge-12875

Fix: Clear browsing history/cache from Microsoft Edge

Site is now secure